# Solspace freeform pro uploads sporadically not working

Tags: solspace-freeform, file-uploads, ajax

I am running Solspace FreeForm 4.2.2 and I have a form that submits via Ajax and has a file upload in the form.  Sporadically we are seeing that the form gets saved in the database but the file does not saved.  So user are trying to upload the file multiple times and it fails everytime.  We are seeing 3 to 10 records in the database for the users depending on how determined they are, none of which have a file saved with it.  Most of the time it works just fine for other users.  We can't find a pattern of file size, file type, OS or browser used.  Internally we cannot replicate the issue but see this happen several times a day.

Anyone experience anything like this? Have any ideas what to try to try and track down / replicate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Could be that your ajax routine is finishing before the file upload finishes?
Internet speed could be a factor over which you have no control. (most throttle uploads) 
Are you using freeforms error reporting back to your page? 
Try an A/B test. Take the form out of running ajax and try the old fashioned way to see if the issue persists. If it does, not your ajax call, something else. If not, maybe something in the javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, taking Ajax out of the equation is probably the best thing to try now and go from there based on the results.